# iPad Issue : Unable to download PDF file from a page within iframe

Tags: javascript, ipad, pdf, iframe

My application uses an iframe to display the classic asp pages with in the MVC4 application.

I am came across an issue with downloading a PDF file from the classic asp page on ipad (Only). It is working on all other browsers.

When i try to download a PDF file it get open in the iframe instead of downloading it as a file.

I am already using Response header with **Content-Disposition** with type **attachment**.

**Markup**

```
<a href="javascript:doILDownload(1054820);">Statement File - 01/31/2014</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
function doILDownload(id)
{
    nDel = 0;
    window.document.location.assign("cincfileIL.asp?id=" + id);
    parent.window.document.getElementById('loadingDialog').style.display = 'none';
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.parent.window.document.getElementById('loadingDialog').style.display = 'none';
    }, 500);
}
```